# cobertura coverage for class with only static methods and private constructors?

Tags: junit, cobertura

how to tell cobertura that the class has only static methods and private constructor hence can not be instantiated and do not include that line in report as not covered.
[image]

version information if required:

```
<plugin>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>2.7</version> 
            <configuration>
            <quiet>true</quiet>
                     <formats>
                           <format>html</format>
                           <format>xml</format>
                     </formats>
                  </configuration> 
            <dependencies>  
                <dependency>  
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>  
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>  
                    <version>5.0.3</version>  
                </dependency>  
            </dependencies>  
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Any solution to this yet @Ajeetkumar?

Comment: Sadly No.......